# How to create a chrome extension clickable notification?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, socket.io

Hey I am using socket io on my client side and I have the following code to generate a notification when a socket event is fired up. The things are working fine but when it comes to creating a new tab when the notification is clicked, I am facing a little trouble. The notification is clicked the moment its created through the socket event function.

What I want to achieve is that the extension should create a new tab only when its clicked and not when the notification is created from the socket event function.

I have tried putting the last line,i.e. which adds listener on the notification, outside the socket event function however it does not work as expected.

The following code is run in the background file of the extension.

```js
socket.on("udf",(msg)=>{
   
    let notifOptions={
        type:"basic",
        title:"You have got a new url ! " + msg[2],
        message:msg[0],
        iconUrl: "https://avatars.dicebear.com/4.5/api/gridy/"+msg[1]+".svg?width=48&height=48"
    }
    chrome.notifications.create(msg[1],notifOptions)
    
    chrome.notifications.onClicked.addListener(chrome.tabs.create({url:"chrome://extensions/"}))
    
    
})
```

Comment: Add `() =>` before chrome.tabs.create

Comment: I am sorry I didn't get that. Do you want me to create an anonymous function inside the listener function?

Comment: Hey thanks! It worked. Could you help me understand what I was missing previosuly?

Comment: Previously your code was calling chrome.tabs.create and passing the result of this call (`undefined`) into addListener.